# How to use timer outside main method in a console application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method in a class that returns the data as List.I need to use timer event for this method to execute in different intervals to check the data.And I need to get the return object from the first method to another method.And I have to call the second method from the Main mehtod in console application.

```
public class clsSample
{
    private static List<string> GetData()
    {            
        data = clsApp.LoadData();
        return data;
    }


    public static void InitTimer()
    {           
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        t.Interval = 50000;
        t.Enabled = true;                     
    }

     private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {             
        GetData();            
     }

}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> data = clsSample.GetData();
    }
}
```

I need to get the return data from GetData() method .But timer need not  be called in the Main method.How is this posible?

Comment: if you're not going to ever call the timer method, then how is it ever going to start the timer?

Comment: And if you want another bit of code to run when the timer elapsed, then you need to call that method from the timer's event handler, otherwise it won't know when it is time to run. You could always expose the event as public so that other classes can hook into the timer in this class and handle the event themselves, so as to be able to collect the data. These are some different ways you could potentially do it, but it depends exactly how you need it to work (which isn't 100% clear from your description)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can call InitTimer method before you load data (inside your list method), that way it will get initiate and same way you can stop it before you return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the following on clsSample :

```
  public delegate void EventRaiser(List<string> data);
  public event EventRaiser OnDataRetrieved;
```

and put this on the timer method

```
 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {                  
     if(OnDataRetrieved !=null)
     {
         OnDataRetrieved(GetData())
     }
 }
```

then handle the event from the program.cs class

Comment: How can I handle the event in program.cs class

Comment: `var _clsSample= new clsSample();
        _clsSample.OnDataRetrieved += OnDataRetrievedEventHandler;

//then define the function 
void OnDataRetrievedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The threshold was reached.");
    }`
normallty when you click += and then tab tab visual studio will generate it for you